# Rename user in github commit

Tags: git, github, repository, alias

I am the maintainer of a project on github having a couple of other contributors. My github handle is different from the user.name in my global git options (github: mname vs. user.name: m.name) and I was not aware of this difference and its consequences.

The effect is, that commits on github are not linked to my github handle. This is annoying for two reasons:

1. The contributor stats for the project are distorted.
2. Commits as m.name are not linked to a github profile

Is there a way to rename the user.name of the commits ? Or is there a possibility to add a second alias on github linking to my account?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On Github, go to https://github.com/settings/emails (Edit profile > Emails)

Add the email address you've been "misusing" as a github handle. That way, the commits you made will appear as made by this account (without modifying anything on any repo).